# Desktop DirectX Surface (WDM)

Tags: c++, directx, wdm

I'm trying to make a screen recording app. Is there a way to use DirectX to capture the entire screen and store it as a texture? This would be in WDM. I know there's a way to get the texture for windows, but what about the entire screen.

I've tried the GDI method of using getDC(null) but that's rather slow for my uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/screencap.aspx#And%20The%20DirectX%20way%20of%20doing%20it%20%3a) three methods: gdi method, directx method and windows media api. When you need to capture entire screen as texture, you should use

```
IDirect3DSurface9->GetFrontBufferData()
```